# Fatal error of using MPI in GPU MapReduce

Tags: cuda, mapreduce, mpi, gpu, distributed-computing

I get a problem in running example of GPMR (a MapReduce framework). I have successfully compiled the examples contained in the framework. But when I run the examples, I get the following error:

Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(106): MPI_Comm_rank(comm=0x8099680, rank=0x97ba5c8) failed
MPI_Comm_rank(64).: Invalid communicator

The commands I issued include "./matmul", "mpiexec -np 2 ./matmul", "mpirun -np 2 ./matmul", where "matmul" is a binary file of a matrix multiply example. and all of them have the same error.

Your answer would be highly appreciated. I am looking forward to your helpful advice.

Regards,

Jay

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by compiling the program via the same mpicxx. Previously, I compiled a lib by ...\bin\mipcxx, while the program via mpicx. That is the problem.